# Consuming WCF Services from Linux Clients

Tags: linux, wcf

I have developed a simple WCF Service to authenticate users against a database in my server and I need to consume my service from Windows clients and Linux clients, afortunately implementing my service in WCF allouds to consume it from any platform(**great advantage over .net remoting**).Consuming it from windows is pretty easy cause there is a lot of documentation about it, my problem is with Linux,so if anyone knows where I can find some good info about this please let me know.

Comment: What programming language do you want to use on Linux?

Answer (score 1):

You can call WCF services from Linux via almost any programming language or platform by exposing your WCF service via XML/HTTP (via basicHttpBinding), SOAP/HTTP (wsHttpBinding) or [REST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203052.aspx).

Then it's just a matter of finding the right libraries for your chosen Linux dev platform and forming and sending the correct messages across the wire/ether.

Of course, since you're building an authn system, you'll want to take a great deal of care to ensure that, for example, you're AT LEAST using HTTPS for your service to prevent a multitude of security vulnerabilities. If you want to employ even stronger security semantics, you may want to expose your service via SOAP / HTTP via the wsHttpBinding and employ WS-Security to protect your messages. This means you'll also need a WS-* stack on the Linux end, of which there are several (e.g. [JAX-WS](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jax_ws_2/), [Java-WS](https://java-ws-xml.dev.java.net/), etc).

HTH.

Comment: Just wondering, what if WCF services hosted on IIS (works with Windows authentication) and I want to consume via Java client?? As, I have a requirement to make it work with almost all types of clients. WCF windows authentication requires a special token generated via NTLM (as per my understanding) and I don't have any idea if I can generate one using Java client.